# Calcular maximo y minimo sin inciar las variables

Tags: java, bucle-for

Quería consultar esto que no puedo resolver. Verán que el hecho de que inicie en 0 significa que cuando ingreso los números (que tiene que ser una serie de 5 numeros ingresados por teclado, perdón por no aclarar esto antes), tiene que ser si o si menor o mayor que 0, sino no toma los menores como debe hacerlo.

Les dejo el código, necesitaría una forma de resolverlo o si necesito hacerlo con arrays, ya que en el ejercicio resuelto no lo usa y se ve así, lo cual esta mal, muchas gracias gente!

```
Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    int numero = 0;
    int numeroMayor = 0;
    int numeroMenor = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        System.out.println("Ingrese un numero: ");

        numero = teclado.nextInt();

        if(numero > numeroMayor){
            numeroMayor = numero;
        }

        if(numero < numeroMenor){
            numeroMenor = numero;
        }  
    }

    System.out.println("El numero mayor es: " + numeroMayor);
    System.out.println("El numero menor es: " + numeroMenor);
```

Comment: intentas verificar cual de dos numero es el mayor y cual es el menor entre ellos?

Comment: Si no quieres inicializar las variables, a numeroMayor 1 pásale el valor del primer número que metan por teclado y a ñúmeroMenor el segundo (si es menor, sino cambia uno por otro), así te funcionará con números menores que 0 también sin problemas

Comment: Mis disculpas, aclare algo en la publicación que no lo hice antes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código está correcto, pero primero debes pedir un número fuera del ciclo y asignárselo inmediatamente al numeroMayor y al numeroMenor, también el ciclo *for* en vez de repetirse 5 veces ahora debe hacerlo 4:

```
Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Ingrese un numero: ");
int temp = teclado.nextInt();

int numero = 0;
int numeroMayor = temp; //el primer valor se lo asignas al mayor
int numeroMenor = temp; //y al menor, de esta forma evitas comenzar con 0

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

    System.out.print("Ingrese un numero: ");
    numero = teclado.nextInt();

    if(numero > numeroMayor){
        numeroMayor = numero;
    }

    if(numero < numeroMenor){
        numeroMenor = numero;
    }  
}

System.out.println("El numero mayor es: " + numeroMayor);
System.out.println("El numero menor es: " + numeroMenor);
```

Espero que te sirva :)

Answer (score 1):

Segun entiendo lo que buscas es una forma de validar dos numeros ingresados, si son mayores o menores entre ellos.

Un ejemplo basico que se me ocurre es el siguiente:
Mientras el usuario no presione una letra se mantiene validando parejas de numeros:

```java
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String salida = "a";
        int numero1 = 0;
        int numero2 = 0;
        int cantidadNumeros = 0;
        while (salida != "s") {
            System.out.println("PARA SALIR PRESIONE CUALQUIER LETRA ");
            System.out.println("INGRESE UN NUMERO: ");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            if(in.hasNextInt()){
                numero1 = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
                if(cantidadNumeros < 2) {
                    System.out.println("INGRESE UN SEGUNDO NUMERO: ");
                    if(in.hasNextInt()) {
                        numero2 = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
                        if (numero1 > numero2) {
                            System.out.println("El numero: " + numero1 + " es mayor que " + numero2);
                        } else{
                            System.out.println("El numero: " + numero1 + " es menor que " + numero2);
                        }
                    }
                    cantidadNumeros = 0;

                    }

                } else {

                    salida = "s";
                }
                cantidadNumeros++;

            }

        }
```

Comment: Mis disculpas, aclare algo en la publicación que no lo hice antes

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que inicializas las variables a 0. Entonces imagina que todos tus números son negativos 0, el resultado es que `numeroMayor` no cambia y siempre será 0.

Lo mismo con `numeroMenor` si todos los números son positivos, entonces `numeroMenor` será 0, que ni si quiera es un número introducido.

Una solución es inicializar `numeroMayor` con el [menor número posible](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MIN_VALUE) y `numeroMenor` con el [mayor número posible](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE):

```
int numeroMayor = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int numeroMenor = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```